# Using Query to select column based on the headers

Tags: google-sheets, filter, columnheader, dynamic-script-loading

I have a dynamic table where columns are moved every now and then. Therefore, I would like to reference my column name in my query. Unfortunately I do not know so well and the internet raises more questions.

My formula looks like this:

```
`=query('X Source'!A:AP, "select D, E, AA, AM, X, A where "&if(month(now())=1,"(month(A)<11)","(month(A)  <=month(now())-2)")&" and (V like 'C & G' or V like 'SAS' or V like 'SXS D' or V like 'DIR') Order By A    desc")

D = Cinter
E = Cluster
AA = Creation Date
AM = Change Ow
X = Title
A = Date`

Do you have any idea ? I would like not to write a script.




I have already tried with the function filter to bypass but there I get no further because of the filtering after month. 

`={FILTER('X Source'!AA:AA, 'X Source'!V:V="SAS",'X Source'!X:X<>"%BY SB%",'X Source'!X:X<>"%SB ONLY%",     month('X Source'! AA:AA)=month(today())-1);FILTER('X Source'!AA:AA,'X Source'!V:V="SXS D",'X     
Source'!X:X<>"%BY SB%",'X Source'!X:X<>"%SB ONLY%"`
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use MATCH to find the numbers of columns, and grab your range in curly brackes so you can refer them as Col1,Col2,Col3 instead of A,B,C

Just to make it more dinamic and you could change your range, I wrapped it in LAMBDA. With the headers I matched all your values and joined them with comma. 'date' only matched that colum. Column V I had my doubts about if it was a mistake when you said which columns was located at which headers. Please change "Title" in ""Col"&MATCH("Title",INDEX(range,1),0)" to the actual desired header title (that now is in V column) so it matches correctly:

```
=LAMBDA(range,
LAMBDA(headers,date,title,query({range}, "select "&headers&" where "&if(month(now())=1,"(month("&date&")<11)","(month("&date&")  <=month(now())-2)")&" and ("&title&" like 'C & G' or "&title&" like 'SAS' or "&title&" like 'SXS D' or "&title&" like 'DIR') Order By "&date&" desc"))(
  JOIN(",",INDEX("Col"&MATCH({"Cinter","Cluster","Creation Date","Change Ow","Title","Date"},INDEX(range,1),0))),
  "Col"&MATCH("Date",INDEX(range,1),0),
  "Col"&MATCH("Title",INDEX(range,1),0)
))
('X Source'!A:AP)
```

In my dummy example with random columns, the inside part of the query would look like this:

> "select Col7,Col3,Col15,Col20,Col11,Col12 where (month(Col12)<11) and
> (Col11 like 'C & G' or Col11 like 'SAS' or Col11 like 'SXS D' or Col11
> like 'DIR') Order By Col12 desc"

---

### UPDATE with other Locale

```
=LAMBDA(range; LAMBDA(headers;date;pl;query({range}; "select "&headers&" where "&if(month(now())=1;"(month("&date&")<11)";"(month("&date&") <=month(now())-2)")&" and ("&pl&" like 'C & G' or "&pl&" like 'SAS' or "&pl&" like 'SXS D' or "&pl&" like 'DIR') Order By "&date&" desc";1))( JOIN(",";INDEX("Col"&MATCH({"Cinter";"Cluster ";"Creation Date";"Change Owner";"Title";"Date"};INDEX(range;1);0))); "Col"&MATCH("Date";INDEX(range;1);0); "Col"&MATCH("PL";INDEX(range;1);0) )) ('X Source'!A1:AS)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. But it does not work. It says it has 5 arguements instead of 3.

Comment: Did you have to change the ranges?, Could you post how it is right now? Probably there's some extra comma or something like that

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Vm5nzF0YQmdKRD-UEJG3Q2ldaWMZLA3f9vqeXW2rZYU/edit?usp=sharing 

here is my dataset I really dont know. In sheet 3 there should pop up the filtered data.

Comment: It was an issue with your locale, had to change all commas into ";", and Cluster title actually had an extra space. Updated answer, check with image in your example!

Comment: Thank you so much! I have just one last question. I need to change the formula a bit for different thinks. I tried it out but I could not figure it out. I put it in the dummy document. Maybe u can help me a last time. Everytime I have to change a bit from the formula I get stuck.

Comment: Apparently some time you were editing the first formula you had some quotation mark misplaced, and it added some extra parenthesis at the end. Also, if you're adding or deleting variables in LAMBDA (like "title" in the formula in column H) you have to add or remove its definitions; meaning, in this case, expressions like: MATCH("Title";INDEX(range;1);0)

Answer (score 0):

You can define the following [Named Function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12504534). **(Data > Named functions > Add new function)**

**Name:**

`BETTERQUERY(range, better_query, headers)`

**Definition**

```
=QUERY({range},IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(better_query,"`")=better_query,1),better_query,
REGEXREPLACE(REDUCE(better_query,REGEXEXTRACT(better_query,REGEXREPLACE(
REGEXREPLACE(better_query,"([()\[\]{}|\\^$.+*?])","\\$1"),"`(.*?)`","`($1)`")),
LAMBDA(acc,cur,SUBSTITUTE(acc,cur,IFNA("Col"&MATCH(cur,INDEX(range,1),0),cur)))),
"`(Col\d+)`","$1")),headers)
```

---

And then use it like this:

```
=BETTERQUERY('X Source'!A:AP',"select `Cinter`, `Cluster`, `Creation date` ...",1)
```

For more information on how this works see [How to Use Column Names in QUERY](https://ztiaa.com/posts/how-to-use-column-names-in-query)

Comment: Thank you for your help but how can I define functions?

Comment: you're right, I should have mentioned it. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my formula based on [this post](https://mudd.com/query-column-header-name-google-sheets/) which is much shorter:

```
=QUERY(INDIRECT(A4&"!A1:Z"),"SELECT "&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1, MATCH(A5,INDIRECT(A4&"!A1:Z1"),0), 4),1,""))
```

- Put sheet name into `A1`
- Put header name (first row) into `A2`
- It will also include the header name in your query, if you want to remove it modify the **first** INDIRECT function and set it to `INDIRECT(A4&"!A2:Z")`

You can also add this function into a named function like this for ease use in other formulas:
[named function version for google sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEh6Q.png)